# Why can both parties feel static electricity

Tags: current, circuits

Sorry I'm new to electrical engineering, trying to clear up some confusion on how static electricty works and why both people feel a shock when touched by static electricity.

When creating a circuit,  Electrons flow from the source through the load back to the source.  However, lightning an electricity seem more like a 1 way current.

If static electricity is one way,  and you're send electrons to someone why would you feel the shock?

But maybe I have a misconception static electricity and the electrons complete the circuit and then return, In this case:

Do you feel the initial shock (Electrons leaving your body) or is the feeling from the electron coming back in?

Comment: Why not both??? If I push someone, do I not feel anything just because I am the one that the force is "coming out of"? A change is charge is a change, and that is what you feel.

Comment: @DKNguyen, good point, but shouldn't the shocks feel different in some sort of way?  Also, is static electricity 1 way current or it completes a circuit

Comment: I don't really know if it should feel different in some sort of way other than that its similar enough no one ever seems to notice it. If you really want to find out then you will have to look at how nerves conduct electricity and how they interact with a shock. The static discharge event itself is one way. It's like twisting the top off of a carbonated drink when the pressure inside the bottle is higher than the atmospheric pressure outside.

Comment: Sensations differ greatly depending on location (and amount of dead skin layers) & surface area  (which affects current density and thus activation potential to nerves)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static discharge is a “one way” circuit phenomenon and, is due to an unequal amount of surface charge on one body compared to the other. At the point of contact, the charge flow (aka current) concentrates for both parties and this means that the current density is higher and therefore the power dissipated in that small contact area is quite noticeable by the nerves for both parties.

If it were a more powerful current flow it could cause a contact burn but luckily static discharges from body to body or body to car are not that powerful.

Notable is the scenario when holding the metal stem of your car key and touching the car door lock. You’ll barely feel anything because you have much more surface skin area contact to the key and the power per square milli metre is much reduced.

Also notable is that if the recipient of the discharge is holding a piece of metal (good surface area contact) and the “emitter” made a small contact touch with the metal, the recipient would feel nothing whereas the guy making the small contact with the metal would feel the localised-to-him discharge.

Comment: A mechanical engineer friend of mine didn't understand that using the car key could eliminate the pain but had worked out that letting his wife get out first would!

Comment: Seems a reasonable alternative @Transistor

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Charge yourself up.  Then hold a coin in your fingers.  Have your "victim" do the same.   Now zap the two coins together.

No shock!

Next, charge yourself up again, but use your coin to zap your victim (avoiding surface of eyeball, inside of nostril, use your imagination.)

You feel nothing.  But they go "YOW!!"

See what's happening?  You weren't feeling the shock in the first place.  You were feeling the pain of having a little patch of skin be vaporized by plasma, where the temperature inside the spark is up around 7,000K (making some hard UV, but no x-rays.)

Do it over and over to the same spot on your finger.  Then examine the spot with a lens.  You'll find a little white scar.  Does it smell like burned hair?  Probably not.  Heh.

When messing with VandeGraaff machines, I notice that, if I let it zap my knuckle a few times, then afterwards, the next spark will always go to the same point on my skin.  If I hold my knuckle very close to the sphere-terminal, in the dark, I can see a purple corona-flame coming from that point on my knuckle.  The scar tissue apparently is more conductive than normal skin.  An ablated pore!  A hole in my integument!

Just remember, DON'T do this to your eyeball surface.   I mean, unless you want to write your initials there, in tiny white dots of scar-tissue.  Hmmm, on second thought, maybe first try that surgically-injected finger-magnet, or that cattle-cryo-branding thing (with dry ice and aluminum CPU heatsinks for fancy skin-art.)  Eyeball kilovolt-electroscarifcation doesn't seem very appropriate for bodymod newbies.